# WSUS after Server Upgrade

Tags: wsus

We have upgraded our 2008 servers to 2016, steps we renamed old servers as OLDSERVER1 and changed IP add new 2016 server kept same server Name and IP as old.
Now in WSUS its still shows as 2008 server, Should delete the servers from WSUS computers and wait?

Comment: `We have upgraded our 2008 servers to 2016, steps we renamed old servers as OLDSERVER1 and changed IP add new 2016 server kept same server Name and IP as old` - That statement isn't clear to me. There's no upgrade path from 2008 to 2016, so you replaced the old servers with new servers, right?

Comment: At any rate, it's perfectly safe to delete the server from the WSUS console. Any active server will "re-register" with WSUS during the next check for updates cycle, which occurs every 22 hours by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see all the servers in WSUS - both the old ones and the new ones, with the right IP addresses and recent check-in times - and the only problem is that the new ones are showing the wrong version of Windows, or that some of the names are wrong, the first thing to try is closing and reopening the WSUS console.  That will usually work, but if not, then yes, it is safe to delete them and let them add themselves back in, so long as you verify that they do all reappear in due course.  (It shouldn't take more than 24 hours, or you can expedite the process as described below.)

If you *can't* see all the servers, or if some of them didn't reappear after you deleted them, you should be able to confirm which ones are missing by looking at the IP addresses.  Check that the missing servers have the right group policy or registry settings to point them at the WSUS server, and correct the settings if necessary.  You can expedite the process of getting a server to check in by running a Windows Update scan and then running `wuauclt /reportnow` on the command line.  If you get an error when scanning then you need to address that problem first.

With Windows Server 2016 in particular, the Windows Update client might not work properly out of the box, in which case you will need to download the latest cumulative update from Microsoft and install it manually.  Once Windows has been updated, the problem usually goes away and at that point the server should be able to check into WSUS normally.

Comment: we only see server with 2008 OS not both

Comment: OK, so the new servers aren't checking in.  It won't hurt to delete the old servers from WSUS but it is unlikely to help, you need to diagnose the problem on the new servers.  As described in my answer, you may need to manually install the latest cumulative update.

Comment: I deleted and it got re-added but no help, where to find the cumulative package?

Comment: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=2019-03%20%22server%202016%22 - choose the cumulative update matching your version of Windows 2016.  (The one with no version number listed is for the original Windows 2016, aka 1607.)

Comment: ... but if the 2016 server got added back in, that's unlikely to be your problem.  Have these servers been cloned or something?

Comment: After discussing with Several experts -- update WSUS to 4.0 or above is the solution